# Update Gitlab Omnibus install via apt-get

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-7

Looking at the update information for GitLab [here](https://about.gitlab.com/update/) and [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update.md), I am unclear as to whether I can upgrade our Omnibus installed GitLab installation (v7.9.2 to v7.11.4) using `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce` or if I should keep using the manual upgrade instructions on that documentation page.

Can I switch to using `aptget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab since added more concise information, a manually downloaded omnibus install cannot directly use the `apt-get`update method.

The method is outlined [here](https://about.gitlab.com/upgrade-to-package-repository/).